# Set a div that has a percentage (%) width to have a min-width of its largest content

Tags: css, width, min, percentage

I am trying to build a side menu that grows with the width of the page, but that when shrunk does not collapse into any of the content of the menu.

Now I could use `min-width:`, and some static pixel number to prevent the menu from collapsing, however since the content of the menu can vary I would like the menu to always have a min-width of the largest element.

This could be achieved using javascript, but is there an elegant CSS solution for this?

Here is a pen with an example, you can slide the editor window to collapse the menu:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/ErikAGriffin/pen/ZjRWed?editors=1100)

Basic element structure:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 30%;
  height:100%;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Variable</li>
    <li>Width</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Do not collapse long text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS grid to simulate such behavior

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  display:grid;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  grid-template-columns:minmax(max-content,30vw);
  height:100%;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Variable</li>
    <li>Width</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Do not collapse long text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works with a `max-width` as well which I forgot to include in my question

Answer (score 1):

Also flexbox

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width:30vw;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Variable</li>
    <li>Width</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>Do not collapse long text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```